# Struts2 ajax theme problem in IE9

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo, internet-explorer-9

We have an running application that is developed in `struts-2.0.14`. In this we used Ajax theme for displaying contents.
This ajax theme is running properly in all browsers except IE9 browsers, In IE9 this ajax theme making problem . The result is showing in new tab instead of showing in target element(div) specified by `targets` property.

**Parent Page**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <s:head theme="ajax" debug="false" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:url id="changePwd" action="changePassword" />
        <s:div theme="ajax" id="pwdDiv" executeScripts="true" href="%{changePwd}" loadingText="Loading..."/>     
    </body>
</html>
```

**Inner page**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<s:form action="changePassword" id="resetPassword"  name="resetPassword">
    <s:textfield name="username" id="username"  />
    <s:password showPassword="true" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" value="%{newpassword}"/>
    <s:password showPassword="true" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="%{confirmpassword}"/>
    <s:submit value="Confirm"  showLoadingText="false"  onclick="clearMsg();" theme="ajax" targets="pwdDiv" executeScripts="true" cssClass="userbutton" />
</s:form>
```

When Submitting the form in Inner Page the resulting page is popup into new tab. actually it should replace the content of `pwdDiv`.
Note: the same working properly in other browsers including (IE7,8)

**Update:**
making  showLoadingText as true making the request as Ajax but the values are passed as null (password,confirm password ect,. -all fields)

Comment: The **Ajax Theme/Ajax tags** is deprecated and replaced by **Dojo Plugin** since Struts-2.1+. But **Dojo Plugin** is deprecated also. The `deprecated of Ajax Theme` means your problem will never be solved in newer version of Struts2. Why don't you update Struts2 to newer version and try the `deprecated` **Dojo Plugin** or use the third party **[Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)**

Comment: The Project already in live, so we can't update struts version. that migration needs lot of resource and time. I need to fix the code for ie9

Comment: What about in other browser, like Firefox? Or check that page in Firefox with Firebug.

Comment: @lschin  checked in Firefox also(including firefox 4) , its working. The problem only occurs in IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `type="button"` in `s:submit` button solve the problem. Don't know what is behind this !

```
<s:submit **type="button"** value="Confirm"  showLoadingText="false"  onclick="clearMsg();" theme="ajax" targets="pwdDiv" executeScripts="true" cssClass="userbutton" />
```